# Lazy list items are not clicking per item only per row

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have been breaking my head trying to get this working but I can't to save my life, I was hoping one of you guys knew how to do it. Basically, I have a list of nature pictures that are loading in a lazy ListView, but my problem is that I can only make the row clickable. I need to make the the individual images clickable. Everything else works like a charm, I really appreciate the help.

Activity:

```
public class AmainActivityNature extends Activity {

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings, mphotos);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button bLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
        bLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntentOne = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this, AmainActivityNature.class);
                AmainActivityNature.this.startActivity(mainIntentOne);

                /* Finish splash activity so user cant go back to it. */
                AmainActivityNature.this.finish();

                /* Apply our splash exit (fade out) and main
                   entry (fade in) animation transitions. */
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enterl, R.anim.animation_leaver);


            }   
            });
        Button bRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
        bRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.testing.image.AMAINACTIVITYNATURE"));
                finish();
            }
            });

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                 switch (arg2)
                 {
                    case 0:
                     Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoOne.class);     
                     startActivity(newActivity0);
                    break;
                    case 1:
                     Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoTwo.class);     
                     startActivity(newActivity1);
                    break;
                    case 2:
                     Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoThree.class);     
                     startActivity(newActivity2);
                    break;
                    case 3:
                     Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoFour.class);     
                     startActivity(newActivity3);
                    break;
                    case 4:
                         Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoFive.class);     
                         startActivity(newActivity4);
                        break;
                        case 5:
                         Intent newActivity5 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoSix.class);     
                         startActivity(newActivity5);
                        break;
                        case 6:
                         Intent newActivity6 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoSeven.class);     
                         startActivity(newActivity6);
                        break;
                        case 7:
                         Intent newActivity7 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoEight.class);     
                         startActivity(newActivity7);
                        break;
                        case 8:
                             Intent newActivity8 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoNine.class);     
                             startActivity(newActivity8);
                            break;
                            case 9:
                             Intent newActivity9 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoTen.class);     
                             startActivity(newActivity9);
                            break;
                            case 10:
                             Intent newActivity10 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoEleven.class);     
                             startActivity(newActivity10);
                            break;
                            case 11:
                             Intent newActivity11 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoTwoelve.class);     
                             startActivity(newActivity11);
                            break;
                            case 12:
                                 Intent newActivity12 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoThirteen.class);     
                                 startActivity(newActivity12);
                                break;
                                case 13:
                                 Intent newActivity13 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoFourteen.class);     
                                 startActivity(newActivity13);
                                break;
                                case 14:
                                 Intent newActivity14 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoFifteen.class);     
                                 startActivity(newActivity14);
                                break;
                                case 15:
                                 Intent newActivity15 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoSixteen.class);     
                                 startActivity(newActivity15);
                                break;
                                case 16:
                                     Intent newActivity16 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoSeventeen.class);     
                                     startActivity(newActivity16);
                                    break;
                                    case 17:
                                     Intent newActivity17 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoEighteen.class);     
                                     startActivity(newActivity17);
                                    break;
                                    case 18:
                                     Intent newActivity18 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoNineteen.class);     
                                     startActivity(newActivity18);
                                    break;
                                    case 19:
                                         Intent newActivity19 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoTwoenty.class);     
                                         startActivity(newActivity19);
                                        break;
                                        case 20:
                                         Intent newActivity20 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoTwoentyone.class);     
                                         startActivity(newActivity20);
                                        break;
                                        case 21:
                                         Intent newActivity21 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoTwoentytwo.class);     
                                         startActivity(newActivity21);
                                        break;
                                        case 22:
                                         Intent newActivity22 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoTwoentythree.class);     
                                         startActivity(newActivity22);
                                        break;
                                        case 23:
                                             Intent newActivity23 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoTwoentyfour.class);     
                                             startActivity(newActivity23);
                                            break;
                                            case 24:
                                             Intent newActivity24 = new Intent(AmainActivityNature.this,NatureTwoTwoentyfive.class);     
                                             startActivity(newActivity24);
                                            break;
                    default:
                      // Nothing do!
                  }
            }
        });

        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        list.setAdapter(null);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public OnClickListener listener=new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    private String[] mphotos={
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/2.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/4.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/6.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/8.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/10.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/12.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/14.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/16.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/18.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/20.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/22.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/24.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/26.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/28.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/30.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/32.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/34.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/36.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/38.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/40.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/42.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/44.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/46.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/48.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/50.jpg"
    };

    private String[] mStrings={
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/1.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/3.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/5.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/7.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/9.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/11.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/13.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/15.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/17.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/19.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/21.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/23.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/25.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/27.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/29.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/31.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/33.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/35.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/37.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/39.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/41.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/43.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/45.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/47.jpg",
            "http:testingsite.com/naturemain/49.jpg"
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater menuinflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuinflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
                switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.inflate:

                    startActivity(new Intent("com.testing.image.ABOUTUS"));
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
}
```

Row XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="120dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/backgroundimage" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="1dip" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="120dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/stub" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="1dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main XML:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
```

Sub-Activity:

```
public class NatureTwoOne extends Activity {

    ImageView image;
    private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...url) {
            //--- download an image ---
            Bitmap bitmap = DownloadImage(url[0]);
            return bitmap;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            bitmaptwo=bitmap;
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response= -1;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection ))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in;
    }

    private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e1){
            Toast.makeText(this,e1.getLocalizedMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    public static Bitmap bitmaptwo;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper);
        new BackgroundTask().execute("http:testingsite.com/natureone/1.jpg");
        Button setWallpaper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WallpaperManager wManager;
                Toast noSong = Toast.makeText(NatureTwoOne.this, "Background Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                noSong.show();
                try {
                    // bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(null);
                    wManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    wManager.setBitmap(bitmaptwo);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Button bLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);
        bLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntentOne = new Intent(NatureTwoOne.this, NatureTwoFifty.class);
                NatureOneOne.this.startActivity(mainIntentOne);
                if(bitmaptwo != null){
                    bitmaptwo.recycle();
                }                              
                /* Finish splash activity so user cant go back to it. */
                NatureOneOne.this.finish();

                /* Apply our splash exit (fade out) and main
                   entry (fade in) animation transitions. */
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_enterl, R.anim.animation_leaver);
            }   
        });
        Button bRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
        bRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.testing.image.NATURETWOTWO"));
                if(bitmaptwo != null){
                    bitmaptwo.recycle();
                }

                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if(bitmaptwo != null){
                bitmaptwo.recycle();
            }
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater menuinflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuinflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.inflate:
            startActivity(new Intent("com.testing.image.ABOUTUS"));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private String[] dataone;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d, String[] mphotos) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        dataone = mphotos;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public int getCountOne() {
        return dataone.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        ImageView photos=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        text.setText("item "+position);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(dataone[position], photos);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do your secondary Activities do? Basically why does each image need its own Activity, do they have nothing in common?

Comment: they each send to image to set it as a background

Comment: Ok, we can drastically shorten your OnClickListener. Please post how you load the image in one of your sub-Activities.

Comment: maybe I didn't explain it properly, the image in the lazy-list view send to another activity where the image gets loaded asynchronously to to an image holder and then it can be set to the background

Comment: Angelo has posted the best way that I know of to give items in each row an OnClickListener. It will take you a little while to customize LazyAdapter to this, but it's the best approach. I'm just trying to show you that you can use Intent's putExtra() method and **one** sub-Activity to display any picture, there is no need for the super long case-statement and 25 sub-Activities.

Comment: wow is that possible? I have like 50 classes to be able to show every single one of those images, what information do you need from me to show me, I would really appreciate it

Comment: Yes, it is possible and easy to do once you see it. But there are a couple different ways you can do this, that is why I would like to see how you load one of your images in one sub-Activity.

Comment: where should I paste the code on the comment or the main question?

Comment: Edit it onto the end of your question (comment have a limited length and no formatting options).

Comment: ok am getting it right now my other computer doesnt have internet access itll just take a couple of minutes

Comment: Which LazyAdapter are you using? Code you post that?

Comment: i can post that code too if you like i really apreciate the help

Comment: ok posted it the adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 50 different specific sub-Activities for the job of one generic... let's address this *and* we'll give both images in each row a click listener.

**To start** you can define these String arrays of JPGs as such:

```
public String[] mPhotos = new String[25];
public String[] mStrings = new String[25];

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstances) {
    ...

    String prefix = "http:testingsite.com/natureone/";
    String suffix = ".jpg";
    for(int index = 1; index <= 25; index++) {
        mPhotos[index - 1] = prefix + (index * 2) + suffix; // evens: 2 - 50
        mStrings[index - 1] = prefix + (index * 2 - 1) + suffix; // odds: 1 - 49
    }
}
```

If you ever add more images or change things around, you have less maintenance now.

**Next** create the appropriate Intent, let's create a generic OnClickListener as a class variable in LazyAdapter:

```
OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Image Index", (Integer) view.getTag());
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

and change getView() in your LazyAdapter:

```
...
text.setText("item "+position);

imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
image.setTag(position + 1);
image.setOnClickListener(mListener);

imageLoader.DisplayImage(dataone[position], photos);
photos.setTag(position + 2);
photos.setOnClickListener(mListener);

return vi;
```

**Now** Change these in one of your sub-Activities and call in ViewActivity (don't forget to update your manifest!):

```
new BackgroundTask().execute("http:testingsite.com/natureone/1.jpg");
```

becomes:

```
mIndex = getIntent().getIntExtra("Image Index", 1);
new BackgroundTask().execute("http:testingsite.com/natureone/" + mIndex + ".jpg");
```

`bLeft` can become:

```
bLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mIndex--;
        if(mIndex < 1)
            mIndex = 50;
        new BackgroundTask().execute("http:testingsite.com/natureone/" + mIndex + ".jpg");
    }
});
```

and `bRight` vica versa. This won't be perfect but it should get you going in the right direction. Hope that helps!

Comment: u don't tell him to try 'HOLDER' inside the adapter ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom `Adapter` for your `ListView` adapter and add `OnCLickListeners` in each `ImageView` that holds the image that you want to be clickable. See [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) for help in creating a custom adapter.

Something like this (inside your custom adapter):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {

View v = inView;
ViewHolder viewHolder; //Use a viewholder for sufficent use of the listview

if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) adaptersContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    v.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
}

    .....

viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Click on imageView
    }i
});

v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Click on listView row, or use an OnItemClickListener as you do already, it will have the same effect
    }
});

    .....

return (v);
}
```

Comment: Hi there how are you, am still learning on android am gonna review your code and ill try to test it

Comment: let me see if am understanding correctly the code that you game me doesnt go into the activity it goes into the lazy list adapter itself?

Comment: @elcuban Yes, this is just part of the `getView` method in your custom adapter so that you get the general idea. It does not go inside the `Activity`.

Comment: oh i see question what if i have multiple activities feeding off of the lazy list adapter would that still work for everyone, for example I also have an animals activity where I load pictures of animals

Comment: @elcuban If you implement everything properly, i cannot find a reason for this to not work.

Comment: thank you Angelo am gonna get working with it, Ill let you know how it went, am still new it might take me a couple of hours to get it properly but I really enjoy programing, Am doing it on my days off am a salesman, also sory if my questions sound too simplistic i really apreciate it

Comment: @elcuban I don't believe there are simplistic questions. Glad i could help:)

Answer (score 1):

You should override OnItemClickListener method instead of OnClickListener

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(cxt, "You selected Item " + (position + 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, how are you, does that mean ill have two list views?

Comment: Sorry, this will have the same effect. It will click the whole list row and not just an item in the list row.

Comment: then you should make your custom adapter for your listview adapter